# Populate html page with XML content in a specific paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Hey guys i'm trying to load up a XML file and then use the data from the XML file in a paragraph with the class of "p2", here is my code so far

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var location;

$(document).ready(function(){
location = $("p").find(".p2");
}

location.append("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  location.append("<tr><td>");
  location.append(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  location.append("</td><td>");
  location.append(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  location.append("</td></tr>");
  }
location.append("</table>");
</script>

<p class="p1"> Paragraph 1 </p>

<p class="p2"></p>

<p class="p3"> Paragraph 3 </p>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting a error or no output?

Comment: It would seem "location" is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
location = $("p").find(".p2");
```

is happening inside the document ready and I would guess your

```
location.append("<table border='1'>");
```

section is being called before the document ready function has executed as it is placed outside it.

Could you try moving it inside the document ready function?

It looks like the document ready is missing a closing bracket too

Comment: That is working, but still no output what so ever in firefox getting this error now Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Users/name/Documents/XmlHtml/[object Object].

Comment: Chrome and Internet explorer are basically saying I am not allowed to load that XML file up, something tells me this is a in-built feature for my protection...